# How do I check codec for a video(mp4) in windows 10?

Tags: codec, windows, android

I'm devleoping an Android application. The [official site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) lists all the codecs which are recommended for videos in Android platform.

I have 2 videos. One of them cannot be played by Android. I would like to check the codec for both files to see is the codec the problem.

What tool do I need in Windows 10 to check such property?

Answer (score 2):

With [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/) (included in the ffmpeg build), run

```
ffprobe yourvideo.ext
```

Or with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), just use the GUI. If you set the display mode to Text you'll be able to see all the details for the streams.